# Javascript two clicks - need one

Tags: javascript

I'm total beginner in JavaScript. The problem is that the code works only when I click on the text two times. I need same, but with one click. The code is on the link:

http://jsbin.com/uTizoKe/1/edit?html,output

I'd really appreciate any help. Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

Move your *script* tag to the end of the body of the HTML, and remove the *onclick* handler from the *table* tag.  This works (here's the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uTizoKe/4/edit)):

```
<script>
    document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].onclick = setTDOnclickEvents();

    function setTDOnclickEvents() {
        var allTDs = document.getElementsByTagName("TD");
        for (var i in allTDs) {
            allTDs[i].onclick = function () {
                txtCellData.value = this.innerHTML;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Another option (rather than calling your function based on a *table* click) is to simply do this:

```
<script>
        var allTDs = document.getElementsByTagName("TD");
        for (var i in allTDs) {
            allTDs[i].onclick = function () {
                txtCellData.value = this.innerHTML;
            }
        }
</script>
```

Another option is (if you want to use the script in the *head* of the document), put everything as a function inside of *window.onload*.

Additionally, it generally a good practice to try to avoid relying on putting event handlers inside HTML elements themselves, and rather handle all that stuff inside your JavaScript.

Comment: I also consider moving your script out of HEAD and at the end of BODY as bad practice.

Comment: What's your reasoning?

Comment: More intuition then reasoning, but my intuition usually serves me well. It does keep all the "metadata" inside HEAD, which is what HEAD is for I guess. I think that if inline JavaScript is bad, then this should be too, after all it's not *that* much more than inline JavaScript concatenated in a block...

Comment: intuition !== reasoning. There's nothing wrong with including your script's after the body.

Comment: @Rolf - I see what you're saying; however, I think the issue is that in large applications, if you end up having a large number of event handlers embedded inside individual HTML elements, then it can become a major pain to change all those every time you change something in the JavaScript file itself (which is why it's usually referred to as a "best practice" to avoid using inline event handlers).

Comment: I agree with the inline event handler thing. I have the habit of using the onload on body, but anything beyond that can, potentially (on large apps, as you say) get me in trouble. But I prefer having all my javascript (and all external resources) in head (as linked .js file usually) and have it run on events, and I believe it's better practice.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `onclick` from the `table` and add it as `onload` to the `body`

[***DEMO***](http://jsbin.com/EjAjijEP/1/edit)

Alternatively, you can use `window.onload` instead of putting it directly in the `body`

[***DEMO***](http://jsbin.com/uJoroRa/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have an onclick attached to the table which calls setTDOnclickEvents. So, only when the user clicks the table will that onclick occur.

What you really want is to bind your elements within the table when the page loads. Using jQuery you could do...

```
$(function() {
setTDOnclickEvents();
});
```

Comment: without jQuery (like here), you just write `document.onload = setTDOnclickEvents`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<body>
```

by

```
<body onload="setTDOnclickEvents()">
```

There are other ways to do that, like you could just write :

```
document.onload = setTDOnclickEvents;
```

Inside your JavaScript

You need to bind your function to an event for it to be fired at all, if it's inside head.

I'd expect your code not to work at all, strange that it does. Perhaps some default behavior somewhere, not worth investigating...

PS: I just saw that you're biding the click event for table to the function, so that would explain the strange behavior. Yeah, remove that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling `setTDOnclickEvents()` on click of the table element.  So you're not attaching the click events until after you've clicked the first time.

Instead, you can move this into the body `onload` attribute.

There are some other improvements you could make to this code to, to make it simpler and more up-to-date.  If interested, please let me know, I'd be happy to help.